# Linkerd not displaying count of requests, success and failure rates

Tags: microservices, linkerd

I am new to linkerd and trying to proxy all the requests to my microservices via linkerd and with file based service discovery. I was able to do it successfully and the requests successfully got registered with the admin dashboard running on port 9990.

But my problem is the dashboard always shows N/A for the success rate and failure rate. It becomes 100% for just a sec the request is received and again goes back to N/A. But I want to keep track of all my request via linkerd i.e I want linkerd to remember the number of requests and the successrate and failure rate.

Here is the screenshot of my problem

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered on the [Linkerd community forum](https://discourse.linkerd.io/t/linkerd-not-displaying-count-of-requests-success-and-failure-rates/123/2). Adding the answer here as well for the sake of completeness:

> The dashboard gives a current snapshot of what's going on - it polls /admin/metrics.json every second and displays the metrics at that time (so at that instant, how many requests, retries, pending requests there are, so if there's nothing going through at that moment, those stats will be 0). For a longer term view of metrics, you'll need something else (see https://linkerd.io/getting-started/admin/index.html#metrics for more info on collecting metrics).
>
> If you're on Kubernetes or DC/OS, you can also check out [linkerd-viz](https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd-viz). Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. Yeah. But since an exploring linkerd and have just began I dont have Kubernetes cluster or DC/OS set up. Looking for a way to get that done without them.